# Python kivy text to speech and Popup in parallel

Tags: python, function, parallel-processing, kivy

I am trying to implement a warning which is using text to speech and a visual warning as popup which should disappear after few seconds. I am using kivy for the user interface. At the moment the code is running with the popup and the voice warning, but the problem is, that the voice warning starts first (I would rather like the popup warning to be first) and I additionally would like both processes to start at the same time. I was not able to solve this issue using `multiprocessing.Process(target.display_warning_popup).start()` and `multiprocessing.Process(target.display_warning_voice).start()`. Followed by `multiprocessing.Process(target.display_warning_popup).join()` and `multiprocessing.Process(target.display_warning_voice).join()`.

This is a snippet of the code that I am using.

```
# imports
import pyttsx3  # for text to speech
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MainApp(App):

    engine = pyttsx3.init()

    # function for displaying popup
    def display_warning_popup():
        content = Label(text="Please reduce the temperature.")
        content.color = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        popup = Popup(title="Warning",
                  content=content,
                  size_hint=(None, None),
                  size=(350, 150))
        popup.open()
        Clock.schedule_once(popup.dismiss, 2)


    # function for text to speech 
    def display_warning_voice(self):
        self.engine.say("Temperature is too high")
        self.engine.runAndWait()

    # function for warning
    def warning(self, is_temperature_too_high):
        if is_temperatrue_too_high:
            self.display_warning_popup()
            self.display_warning_voice()
```

Comment: I would try binding the `self.display_warning_voice` to the `on_open` event from the `Popup`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding the voice warning to the `on_open` event of the `Popup` results in both warnings appearing at about the same time. The `Popup` class is an extension of the `ModalView` class, and the documentation is [here](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.modalview.html).

After incorporating this change and correcting some other minor problems with the code, here is what your code looks like:

```
# imports
import pyttsx3  # for text to speech
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MainApp(App):

    engine = pyttsx3.init()

    def build(self):
        return Button(text='click here', on_press=self.warning)

    # function for displaying popup
    def display_warning_popup(self):
        content = Label(text="Please reduce the temperature.")
        content.color = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        popup = Popup(title="Warning",
                  content=content,
                  size_hint=(None, None),
                  size=(350, 150))
        popup.bind(on_open=self.display_warning_voice)
        popup.open()
        Clock.schedule_once(popup.dismiss, 2)


    # function for text to speech
    def display_warning_voice(self, *args):
        self.engine.say("Temperature is too high")
        self.engine.runAndWait()

    # function for warning
    def warning(self, is_temperature_too_high):
        self.display_warning_popup()

MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will try to implement this as soon as I have time. I will accept the answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: Both events are still not really parallel. There is approximately 0.5 s between the popup showing up and the speech warning.

Comment: I changed the order of the popup.open() and the popup.bind(...), this way there is not delay between both events.

Comment: @MrYouMath, the order of those calls matter, the `bind` should be called first. The `bind` statement doesn't actually call the `display_warning_voice` method, it just arranges for it to be called when the `Popup` opens. If you call `bind` after the call to `popup.open()`, you might miss the event, and the voice warning might not get called.

Comment: Hmm ... but if I change the order, both events happen with a delay.